# Vue Get uploaded files url

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I am using vue and element ui to upload files. But I don't know how to get upload files url (basically I want to check the file type - jpg or pdf and then do something).

```
<div id="app">
<el-upload action="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" list-type="picture-card" :on-preview="handlePictureCardPreview" :on-remove="handleRemove">
<i class="el-icon-plus"></i>
</el-upload>
<el-dialog :visible.sync="dialogVisible">
<embed width="100%" :src="dialogImageUrl">
</el-dialog>

<p>file type: "{{ checkType() }}"</p>
</div>

var Main = {
data() {
  return {
    dialogImageUrl: '',
    dialogVisible: false
  };
},
methods: {
  handleRemove(file, fileList) {
    console.log(file, fileList);
  },
  handlePictureCardPreview(file) {
    this.dialogImageUrl = file.url;
    this.dialogVisible = true;
  },
  checkType(){

     var filename =  this.dialogImageUrl;  
     return filename.split('.').pop(); 

  }
 }
}
```

Please Help...

I have add this try to get URL..but it doesn't work..

```
var filename = document.getElementsByTagName("embed")[0].src; 
console.log(filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use :before-upload attribute of el-upload. please take look of changed code.

```
<div id="app">
<el-upload action="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" **:before-upload="checkType"** list-type="picture-card" :on-preview="handlePictureCardPreview" :on-remove="handleRemove">
<i class="el-icon-plus"></i>
</el-upload>
<el-dialog :visible.sync="dialogVisible">
<embed width="100%" :src="dialogImageUrl">
</el-dialog>

<p>file type: "{{ checkType() }}"</p>
</div>

var Main = {
data() {
  return {
    dialogImageUrl: '',
    dialogVisible: false
  };
},
methods: {
  handleRemove(file, fileList) {
    console.log(file, fileList);
  },
  handlePictureCardPreview(file) {
    this.dialogImageUrl = file.url;
    this.dialogVisible = true;
  },
  **checkType(file){**
    console.log(file.type);
    // do your action here based on file.type
     var filename =  this.dialogImageUrl;  
     return filename.split('.').pop(); 

  }
 }
}
```

Comment: console.log(file.type); -> TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined -> I got this error...I don't really understand why I cant check the type -> I was coding like this in the first place, then changed to var filename = document.getElementsByTagName("embed")[0].src; but both of them don't works.

Comment: did you tried with manual upload method from here [here] http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/upload#upload on submit action. try if it gives you file object.

Comment: Did you get an answer for this? I am trying to access the url after uploading the image in order to display/preview the image.